# Disable Standard Button based on conditon

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

I would like to hide **Add Products** button whenever PriceBook is not assigned to OpportunityLineItem and then need to display it when the same gets assigned.

*I have asked this question because I have overrided the Add Products button*

Suggestions Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to dynamically add or remove buttons from page layouts. Only workarounds.

[1/2] Create two record types and use workflow to assign the record types based on the Opportunity having or not the PriceBook. Use different page layouts for the record types, one with the button one without.

Comment: But we do not have record Type for "Opportunity Product"  right?Can we achieve the same in "Opportunity" Record Types itself?

Comment: Oh. I was talking about the Opportunity RecordType. The PriceBook is not set on the OpportunityLineItem, it is actually set on the Opportunity, on the field PriceBook2Id.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to dynamically add or remove buttons from page layouts. Only workarounds.

[2/2] Create a visualforce page that uses `<apex:detail>` and `<apex:relatedList>` to replicate the standard page and use javascript to hide/show the button. Then create a page layout that receives only this visualforce page. (this is not a great solution)